# iOS - Scroll TextView to top when it's in a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` inside a custom `TableView` cell.  I want the text view to scroll to the top by default.  I usually do it this way in regular views:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let fixedWidth = bioView.frame.size.width
    bioView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSize = bioView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrame = bioView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    bioView.frame = newFrame;
    bioView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location:0, length:0))
}
```

bioView is my text view object.  However, this doesn't work in my case since I can't reference the `textview` in the `ViewController` class and can only do so in the `CustomCell` class and that class cannot override `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  Any help?

Comment: Since all cells are reused can't you have a reference to your custom cell object in your viewcontroller and access the textview etc from there?

Comment: Tried that now, didn't workk :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    [cell.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
    return cell;
}
```

Swift 3.0:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! DemoCell
    cell.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location:0, length:0))
```

It works! However, the table has to scroll for the changes to take effect, best way I found so far.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, didn't work either :( Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried this and its working fine, I might have understood you problem wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewController which handles `UITableViewDelegate` events, override `willDisplayCell` method. Identify your textView from Cell and write the code to scroll.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I didn't find a "willDisplayCell" I tried doing that on the cellForRowAt method but it didn't work either.  I even created a reference to the cell and used that in the viewDidLayoutSubviews but didn't work either.  Any other ideas? Really appreciate it!

Comment: This is the name of the function in Swift: func tableView(UITableView, willDisplay: UITableViewCell, forRowAt: IndexPath)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried doing the scrolling, either with `scrollRangeToVisible()` or setting `contentOffset` to `.zero` in `awakeFromNib`, `willDisplayCell`, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. These all get executed, but the scrolling is still reset (by AutoLayout?) some time subsequent to this.

For a cell that is on screen when the UITableView appears, performing the scroll in `willDisplayCell` does not "stick." It *does* work if the cell is scrolled away and scrolls back on screen.

For a cell that is already on screen that has a UITextView with "too much" text so that it scrolls out the bottom of the TextView, the only way I have found to make the text scroll to the top is to set either `scrollRangeToVisible()` or `contentOffset` in the `viewDidAppear()` of the UITableViewController. Even `viewWillAppear()` did not work.

One drawback is that this solution causes a jump in the scroll location after the TableView appears on screen, even in a `performWithoutAnimation` block.

You can put the code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and it will work, but as mentioned this gets called several times, and the text will scroll back to the top with every orientation change, which may not be desirable.